# Chrome desktop - Can't connect to current desktop session

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

After installing chrome-remote-desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 (with a priori no problems). **I cannot connect to the desktop session I am using on the machine.**

The problem is that when I try to connect it asks me which session I would like to log in to a new Xsession or a remote session but not to the desktop session that I am running on the machine.

Moreover, sometimes if I try to run the new Ubuntu desktop session (clicking on the option of the white window pop up) then I go to a just black window. I have tried to repeatedly remove and installing it several times. I have also checked that the current user is part of the chrome-remote-desktop group.

Comment: I've seen a similar question, and the solution involved manually patching chrome-remote-desktop. Consider using something else, e.g. Anydesk.

Comment: I do not really mind manually patching chrome-remote-desktop, but my knowledge on this is very limited. @HolyBlackCat